# Install and use OpenCV from source

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I have tried [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) to install opencv. The terminal output after installing was:

```
OpenCV 2.4.13 ready to be used
```

But when I try to import the module, it says the module doesn't exist.

When I tried:

```
pkg-config opencv --cflags
```

to check if opencv was installed, I got:

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

How can I fix this? Is there any other way to install opencv?

Comment: You probably need to add the installation path for Python modules to PYTHON_PATH. As for pkg-config info, this doesn't seem to install that - or maybe it does, but to some nonstandard path, too.

Comment: How can I add the installation path?

Comment: @Sibi, which python version are you using, if you are running `Python2`, you should be able to download the pre-built opencv2 and install it without any compilation. Make sure `cv2.pyd` is inside your Python `site-package` folder

Comment: @MaThMaX I'm using Python3

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Python3`, You can only choose to build your own `cv2.pyd`. There is no pre-built version for you to download.

I found another [**link**](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) of installing the Package, which is installing from the source, means that you need to compile the source code.

The general idea is to download the source code you want first. After that, yor will use `CMake` to build the libraries and the Python wrapper (based on the specific Python version you are using). After build successful, you will then get the `cv2.pyd` and several OpenCV libraries, you just copy them into your Python `site-package`. Finally you should be able to `import cv2`.

I did the same thing in `Window` for `Python3.3, 3.4, and 3.5` by following this [**tutorial**](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html#gsc.tab=0), the general idea is the same but only on different platform. I think it should be helpful as a reference for you.

Comment: "copy them into your Python `site-package`" is non-maintainable. Doesn't it have some distutils script like all normal people do?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, agree! To some certain extent, this way is not maintainable. But if you know exactly which are the thing you need, I personally still think it is a doable way (such as in this case, I know it is `cv2.pyd` plus several dynamic libraries). However, the only reason I don't use `distutils` or pre-built packages is that there are no available ones for `Python3`, at least as far as I know...